# SSAS Dynamic Dimension Security based on another dimension attribute

Tags: security, ssas, dimensions

In my project I have to apply security based on a dimension attribute.
I think the best way to explain my scenario is with an example, if you need more info please request me and I'll love to told you if it will help me find a solution.

I have some main dimension, the dimcustomer, dimseller, fact, data and geographic.
The fact table are related with dimseller ids, the dimcustomer is related to the dimseller based on one dimseller specific attribute(CNPJ)(another dimensions that i didnt described are related the same way).

So my goal is to apply a role security based on the dimseller CNPJ, so then when the user related with that seller trys to browse data he will be allowed to view only the data that are related to his seller CNPJ.

Table example:

```
DIM Seller:               DIM Customer                  FactTable
id  name  cnpj            id name    dimseller.cnpj     dimseller.id  dimcustomerid measure
1   ME    1234            1  guest1  1234               1             1               50,00
2   you   5678            2  guest2  5678               2             2              100,00
```

So if i login as ME i will be able to se that i have the customer guest1 with one sold product that was sold by 50 bucks.

Got my point?

What is the best way of doing it?

For now I'm considering the following guide: [Claim Authentication with dynamic dimension security](http://varadarajbhat.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/forms-based-authenticationfba-configuration-for-performancepoint-2010-and-sharepoint-2010-using-claims-authentication/#comment-41), but at that way I should define it attribute by attribute.

Is there a way that i can define this security need? I can easy filter the data using sql statements, but i have no ideia how i can apply this kind of security in the ssas.

Thank you guys anyway!

Answer (score 0):

To apply security within a dimension, you need to use `roles`. For each roles, you can then specify which element in the cubes/dimensions that are available to that role. So, what you got to do is to create a role by CNPJ that will be able to view only their CNPJ.